# grep not finding name in text file

Tags: shell, grep

text file:

```
Annemie;014588529    
Stefaan;011802367    
Jan;032569874    
Hans;015253694
```

Trying to find the phonenumber by name but it doesn't display anything

```
echo -n ""
read name
number=`grep '$name' numbers.txt | awk -F';' '{print $2}'`
echo "$number"
```

Comment: Why not echo name, then just run the grep to debug the code

Comment: Replace `'$name'` by `"$name"` to let the shell replace the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes avoid expansion of variables.
You are searching the string `$name` inside `numbers.txt`.
Try this instead:

```
echo -n ""
read name
number=$(grep "$name" numbers.txt | awk -F';' '{print $2}')
echo "$number"
```

or even better to reduce the pipe (awk can perform the grep directly):

```
echo -n ""
read name
number=$(awk -F';' -v name="$name" '$1 ~ name {print $2}' numbers.txt)
echo "$number"
```

Comment: To increase readability and simplify (avoid) escaping, you should use the `$(..)` form of command substitution, instead of the old-style backticks.

Comment: Also, your **`awk` expression will fail** if `name` contains a whitespace, or `/`. If you insist on using `awk` instead of `grep`, you should write: `number=$(awk -F';' -v pat="$name" '$1 ~ pat {print $2}' numbers.txt)`. (Note you can match only names in `$1`, not the complete record.)

Comment: However, the proper `awk` search would search for **fixed substrings**, not patterns (like `grep -F`: `awk -F';' -v name="$name" 'index($1,name) {print $2}'`. (That's important because user input is invalidated, so it's risky to include it in `awk`, verbatim.

Comment: I do like `$()` better, but the original code used backticks so I matained them. Thank you for your comment about the failures in the event of spaces and slash. As for the "searching only in the name part", I thought it was just overkill (and noone seemed to worry about that until now). As for the fixed substring, I would personally allow regex, since it is more practical and not likely to cause a problem by itself: I cannot think of a name with reserved characters

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes prevent the shell variable `name` to [expand](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Try like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Enter name: " name
number=$(grep -F "$name" numbers.txt | awk -F';' '{print $2}')
echo "$name => $number"
```

Also, you should use `-F` for fixed string grepping, avoid old-style backtick [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), and use `$(..)` instead. If you wish, you can use `-p` for `read` prompt (in POSIX shells, `sh`/`bash` included).